How can you derive Conjunction if your only underived rule of inference is modus ponens?
Suppose you are working with a logistic system for the propositional calculus that only has one underived rule of inference, namely Modus Ponens.  How can you derive Conjunction in it?
Rule 1: A, if A then B; therefore B.
Conjunction: A, B; therefore A and B.
Feel free to state the axioms, and definitions you would use for your system.
One such system I know of, is J. B. Rosser's system.
It has the following definitions, and axioms, and undefined connectives.
Undefined connectives: not, and
Definition: A or B = not(not A and not B)
Definition: if A then B = not(A and not B)
Definition: A iff B = (if A then B) and (if B then A)
Axiom 1. If A then (A and A)
Axiom 2. If A and B then A
Axiom 3. If (If A then B) then
[(if not(B and C) then not(C and A)]
The only problem with his system is, conjunction is derived after he proves 18 theorems, and 13 derived rules of inference.  That's a long time to wait for conjunction.

At a minimum, you need axioms involving conjunction to derive anything with it using MP alone. For example, Hilbert systems have only MP as an inference rule, and they often take A → (B → A ∧ B) as an axiom.

If you have negation, you can define     A ∧ B := ¬( A → ¬ B), and try applying whatever axioms you are working with.  This lets you only have axioms involvong →, ¬. We cannot answer any " how do you derive Y" without knowing what Axioms you are working with.

@michael, I was hoping for the answerer  to choose his or her own axioms.  You are free to invent your own system, I'm thinking.

I’m voting to close this question because it's a low-level homework problem.

If you wanted to be as economical as possible, you could just take Conjunction as an Axiom and prove it with a proof of length 1.

Indeed, I could give a one-liner in Coq (which is Calculus of Inductive Constructions), where it follows by definition of AND, doesn't even need MP.  And what would be the point?  There are so many possible systems, and the interesting distinctive features, if that's the goal, cannot just be fished by asking random questions.  This question (IMO) is as trivial as it is unmotivated. --  Maybe an interesting question could be if/how is MP not enough, and what is the minimum set of assumptions/the minimum machinery needed to do propositional logic?  Maybe.

@julio, I think Rosser's system was designed with minimality in mind.  But I was thinking of adding just one axiom, and perhaps altering Rosser's Axiom 3, just to derive Conjunction sooner.  The reason I want to use a system with only modus ponens, is because it's relatively trivial to prove Rosser's system is analytic., and I have the additional intent of proving deductive completeness.  Then after developing the system , show the added axiom can be eliminated

@conifold, that's how it's done in Rosser's system.  He proves that statement.

There are many equivalent axiom systems for propositional calculus; you can choose Conjunction and negation version as well as a "full" one, suitable for treating Intutitionist Logic and Classical one.

A common conjunction introduction axiom which I personally prefer is (A->B)->((A->C)->(A->(B&C))). This version is suitable for many logics like Relevance logics, as well as Classical and Intuitionistic logic. It’s a bit harder to use than A->(B->(A&B), but that version is invalid in some important systems.
